# Appium Maven: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.proxy2.$Proxy10.proxyClassLookup()

Tags: java, maven, appium

When running test from terminal mvn test, Im encountering the following error

Running test via Intellij testng plugin works as expected
Only when running via a mvn command
Java: 15.0.2
Maven: 3.8.2
Appium Desktop: v1.21.0

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.proxy2.$Proxy10.proxyClassLookup()
> at Registration.NewRegistrationTest.RegisterUser(NewRegistrationTest.java:15)
> `

Base Test

```java
package Pages.base;

public class BaseTest {

    public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    public CommonUtils util = new CommonUtils();

    @BeforeSuite
    public void installAppBeforeSuite(){
        driver = util.getAndroidDriver();
        driver.installApp("{AppLocation}");
    }
    @BeforeClass
    public void launchApp(){
        if (driver==null) {
            System.out.println("Driver Null Creating New Driver");
            driver = util.getAndroidDriver();
        }
        driver.launchApp();
    }
//    @AfterClass
//    public void closeApp() {
//        driver.terminateApp("com.getmyboat_v1");
//    }
}
```

Base Page

```java
package Pages.base;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class BasePage {

public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
public WebDriverWait wait;

    public BasePage(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
        this.wait= new WebDriverWait(this.driver,10);

    }

    public void hideKeyboard(){
        driver.hideKeyboard();
    }
    public void showKeyboard(){
        driver.getKeyboard();
    }

    public void pressEnter(){
        ((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
    }
}
```

Page Object

```java
package Pages.common;

import Pages.base.BasePage;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import java.time.Duration;

public class footerComponent extends BasePage {

    public footerComponent(AppiumDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30)), this);
    }

    @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().text(\"Account\")")
    public MobileElement accountBtn;

    @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().text(\"Search\")")
    public MobileElement searchBtn;

    @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().text(\"Inbox\")")
    public MobileElement inboxBtn;

    @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().text(\"Calendar\")")
    public MobileElement calendarBtn;

    public void clickAccount() {
        accountBtn.click();
    }

    public void clickSearch() {
        searchBtn.click();
    }

    public void clickInbox() {
        inboxBtn.click();
    }

    public void clickCalendar() {
        calendarBtn.click();
    }
    }
```

POM.xml

```xml
 <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>15</source>
                    <target>15</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <testFailureIgnore> true </testFailureIgnore>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>/Users/adambethlehem/IdeaProjects/Appium/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: Where is this class `Registration.NewRegistrationTest.RegisterUser(NewRegistrationTest.java:15)` code?
Update the question so then we can see it.

Comment: The issue was my terminal JAVA_HOME env was still set to 16